# Json result data not showing properly

Tags: php, html, json, select

Hi i have small project which will display news from last 4,6 weeks. I have created select box   which will ask for news from last 4,6 weeks. and submit button.So user select news from select box and click on submit button and he will get the result. But i am not getting proper ouput not even getting any error. By default i dont know why the ouput displaying data from database. And my submit button is not even showing active.I am making small mistake which is not able to identify. Thanks.

js file

```
$.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "ajax/edit_news.php",
          dataType : 'json',
          cache: false,
          data: {'aktion' : 'edit-news'},
          success: function(data){
          $('#editnews').html(data.html);
          }
        });
```

Here is my code:

```
<?php
chdir('..');
include 'constant/const_system.inc.php';
include 'functions/ad_json.inc';
include 'functions/ad_formulare.inc';
include 'constant/const_system_db.inc.php';  //database file

$return = array();
if(isset($_POST['BtnSubmit']))
    {

        if(($_POST['news'])==4){

            $sql=" SELECT DISTINCT ad_news_texte.headline, ad_news.datum_archiv
        FROM ad_news_texte
        INNER JOIN ad_news_oe ON ad_news_texte.news_id = ad_news_oe.id_ad_news
        INNER JOIN ad_news ON ad_news_oe.id_ad_news = ad_news.id
        WHERE ad_news.datum_archiv
        BETWEEN curdate( ) - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK( curdate( ) ) +28
        DAY AND curdate( )
        ";

            $sql_select=mysql_query($sql);
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_select)) {
                echo $row['headline'] . " " .$row['datum_archiv'] ;
                echo "<br>";
            }
        }
        if(($_POST['news'])==6){

            $sql=" SELECT DISTINCT ad_news_texte.headline, ad_news.datum_archiv
        FROM ad_news_texte
        INNER JOIN ad_news_oe ON ad_news_texte.news_id = ad_news_oe.id_ad_news
        INNER JOIN ad_news ON ad_news_oe.id_ad_news = ad_news.id
        WHERE ad_news.datum_archiv
        BETWEEN curdate( ) - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK( curdate( ) ) +42
        DAY AND curdate( )
        ";

            $sql_select=mysql_query($sql);
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_select)) {
                echo $row['headline'] . " " .$row['datum_archiv'] ;
                echo "<br>";
            }
        }
    }
if($param['aktion'] == 'edit-news')
    {
        $html = '                                           
                                                                <form name="UserInformationForm" method="POST" action="#">

                                                <select name="news">
                                                                <option value="4" '. (($_POST['news']=="4")  ?  "selected=selected" : "" ) .'>Show news from last 4 weeks</option>
                                                                <option value="6" '. (($_POST['news']=="6") ?  "selected=selected" : "") .'>Show news from last 6 weeks</option>
                                                </select>
                                                <br/><br/>
                                        <input name="BtnSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit" >
                                                                </form>             


                                ';
        $return = array(
                        'status' => 1,
                        'html'  => $html
                        );

        echo json_encode($return);
        die();
    }
?>
```

And its showing output like this:
[image]

Comment: post you js code here

Comment: js or json ? i am not using js..

Comment: It doesn't make sense for the script to echo HTML and also echo JSON. If the client expects HTML, the JSON won't be meaningful. And if the client expects JSON, the HTML will mess up the parse.

Comment: If you're not using Javascript, why are you echoing JSON? You need a script on the client that will parse the JSON and format it properly.

Comment: yes @Barmar you are right but do you have solution for the same because i am quite new of using JSON data format.

Comment: sorry i have updated my code. i was confused i thought u were asking for json code. I have updated my js code in question

Comment: @Anish did u please find any solution ?

Comment: Now that I've looked closer, I'm not sure what the problem is. You echo HTML only when `$_POST['BtnSubmit']` is set, and you echo JSON only when `$param['aktion'] == 'edit-news'`. I don't think they should happen in the same call to the script.

Comment: @Barmar plz tell me if you knw the solution i have problems with the Json

Comment: I said I don't know what the problem is. How could I have a solution if I don't know the problem?

Comment: @user3702602 you have to change your logic little bit

Comment: tell me what is the use of status in json

Comment: @Anish its still not runnig yet :(

Comment: now what is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You are returning a invalid `json` mixed with html, that's why its not working, here is code you need to change

```
//Change this in both places 
...
$news = '';
$sql_select=mysql_query($sql);
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_select)) {
            $news .= $row['headline'] . " " .$row['datum_archiv'] ;
            $news .= "<br>";
}
...

//and return news like below 

$return = array(
    'status' => 1,
    'news' = $news
 );
//Return the json 
header('Content-Type: application/json');
exit(json_encode($return));
```

Comment: Why do you think `mysql_fetch_array()` won't work? It returns both numeric and named columns.

Comment: You're thinking of `mysql_fetch_row`, which only returns numeric arrays.

Comment: I have tried but no luck yet what changes you have  done

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "ajax/edit_news.php",
              dataType : 'html',
              cache: false,
              data: {aktion: 'edit-news'},
              success: function(data){
              $('#editnews').html(data.html);
              }
            });
```

and do echo html . dont json

like `echo $html;` . This will fix your issue

Comment: as per ur answer its running but it doesn't even require js file now. If i am using this condition: if($param['aktion'] == 'edit-news') then nothing is showing. so whats the use of js and ajax here ?

Comment: what?? . then how you are  echoing ?

Comment: if i remove if condition and directly add echo $html at the bottom then it will echo...

Comment: do remove your condition .just use  the ajax code which I provide. There no big change in the logic. instead of echoing json we are just echoing html. Try that and let me if it works for you. Also there is a  small change in ajax code . I have updated that .

Answer (score 0):

Add below line in the top of file
    header('Content-Type: application/json');